# Is it possible, for testing purposes, to releasean app on Google Play which I alone can access

Tags: android, google-play

I know one can have a feature to enable License API (LVL) testing, but to test the "complete Google Play User experience" before releasing to the world would also be nice.

I think this is a technical question and not a business related question so hope it is allowed to stay on-line.

As ever many thanks in advance.

Paul

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to restrict an App in the Play store to one user.

When publishing a apk for the first time it will only be visible when searching for the exact package name. So maybe you have enough time to test it until it shows up in regular search results.